# Binding boost::asio::steady_timer::async_wait

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I want to turn this call:

```
timer.async_wait(handler);
```

into this call:

```
func(handler);
```

So I tried using `std::bind`:

```
#include <functional>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>

using std::bind;
using std::function;

using boost::asio::io_service;
using boost::asio::steady_timer;
using boost::system::error_code;

int main(int, char**) {
  using namespace std::placeholders;

  io_service io_s;
  steady_timer timer (io_s);

  // error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  function<void(function<void(const error_code&)>)> bound =
    bind(&steady_timer::async_wait, timer, _1);

  return 0;
}
```

But it wont compile! When compiled like this:

```
g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -Wall -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_system -o bin main.cpp
```

The error message is this:

```
main.cpp:22:46: error: no matching function for call to 'bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, boost::asio::steady_timer&, const std::_Placeholder<1>&)'
 bind(&steady_timer::async_wait, timer, _1);
```

I've tried various things (like casting, template arguments, function objects) but I just can't get it to compile.

I'm using Boost ASIO 1.58 and [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/async_wait.html) says the following:

```
template<
    typename WaitHandler>
void-or-deduced async_wait(
    WaitHandler handler);
```

And [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/WaitHandler.html) you can see what a WaitHandler is. I don't understand what `void-or-deduced` mean but I'm thinking it might be what's giving me a tough time? I've stared at this problem for so long now that I think I've gotten tunnel vision.

How do I properly use `std::bind` in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ How to Reference Templated Functions using std::bind / std::function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727313/c-how-to-reference-templated-functions-using-stdbind-stdfunction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of object returned from an initiating function (`async_*`) is *dependent* on the handler type provided to the initiating function.  The documentation indicates this variant with its `void-or-deduced` type.

Trying to use `function` and `bind` here will have multiple problems:

- the function signature for [`timer.async_wait()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/async_wait.html) cannot be resolved without first specifying the exact handler type that will be provided so that the return-type can be deduced
- changing the handler type to `std::function<...>` can have the unintended consequences, as the default `asio_handler_*` hooks will be invoked rather than custom hooks.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32892581/1053968) answer for more details about handler hooks.

Instead, consider using a custom functor to accomplish the binding, while allowing handler types to be properly passed through to Asio:

```cpp
/// @brief Custom functor used to initiate async_wait operations.
template <typename Timer>
class async_wait_functor
{
public:
  async_wait_functor(Timer& timer): timer_(timer) {}

  template <typename WaitHandler>
  auto operator()(WaitHandler handler)
  {
    return timer_.async_wait(handler);
  }

private:
  Timer& timer_;
};

/// @brief Auxiliary factory function for binding a timer.
template <typename Timer>
async_wait_functor<Timer> bind_async_wait(Timer& timer)
{
  return async_wait_functor<Timer>(timer);
}

...

auto func = bind_async_wait(timer);
func(handler);
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06813663060d8be6) using a custom functor:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>    
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>

/// @brief Custom functor used to initiate async_wait operations.
template <typename Timer>
class async_wait_functor
{
public:
  async_wait_functor(Timer& timer): timer_(timer) {}

  template <typename WaitHandler>
  auto operator()(WaitHandler handler)
  {
    return timer_.async_wait(handler);
  }

private:
  Timer& timer_;
};

/// @brief Auxiliary factory function for binding a timer.
template <typename Timer>
async_wait_functor<Timer> bind_async_wait(Timer& timer)
{
  return async_wait_functor<Timer>(timer);
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io_service);
  auto handler = [](const boost::system::error_code&) {
    std::cout << "in handler" << std::endl;
  };

  auto func = bind_async_wait(timer);
  func(handler);

  timer.cancel();
  io_service.run();
}
```

When ran, it outputs:

```
in handler
```

---

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html#boost_asio.reference.asynchronous_operations.return_type_of_an_initiating_function) details how the return type is determined:

> By default, initiating functions return `void`. This is always the case when the handler is a function pointer, C++11 lambda, or a function object produced by `boost::bind` or `std::bind`.
>
> For other types, the return type may be customised via [...] a specialisation of the [`async_result`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_result.html) template, which is used both to determine the return type and to extract the return value from the handler.

For example, Boost.Asio specializes `boost::asio::async_result` for `boost::asio::use_future`.  When `boost::asio::use_future` is provided as the handler to an iniating function, the return type is `std::future`.

Comment: Wow, wouldn't have thought that the rabbit hole goes _that_ deep. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Use a lambda instead:

```
auto func = [&timer](const function<void(const error_code&)>& cb) {
    timer.async_wait(cb);
};
func(handler);
```

`bind` is not the most convenient thing to use in the first place, but it is especially painful here as you are dealing with an *overloaded* member function. That is, if you just say `&steady_timer::async_wait`, you are being ambiguous and the compiler cannot determine which of the overloads you are referring to.

You can fix this by [explicitly casting to the correct type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942426/how-to-specify-a-pointer-to-an-overloaded-function), but that will be quite a pain for a complex type like `steady_timer`. The lambda elegantly works around the problem and also offers the compiler additional opportunities for optimizations, as it's less opaque than the type created by `bind`.

Comment: In the documentation it only lists one signature for `async_wait` so in my head it _shouldn't_ be overload (since overloading implies multiple signatures). Is it the `void-or-deduced` return type magic that makes it overloaded? Wouldn't it be more correct then to list multiple signatures in the documentation?

Comment: Changing the handler type can have unintended consequences, as the default `asio_handler_*` hooks will be invoked rather than custom hooks.