# C++ How to bind and invoke a templated type method

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand the syntax to bind to a templated type's method. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727313/c-how-to-reference-templated-functions-using-stdbind-stdfunction) seemed similar to my question, but didn't seem to give an example of binding and calling a templated type method.

Here's my code sample:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void DidSomething(int x)
{
    cout << "Did something x = " << x << endl;
}

template <typename T>
class Outer
{
public:
    void StartSomething()
    {
        Inner inner;

        // below lines cause
        // error C2893 Failed to specialize function template
        //'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'

        auto fnGlobal = std::bind(&::DidSomething);
        inner.DoOneThing(fnGlobal);

        auto fnMethod = std::bind(&Outer<T>::DidSomething, this);
        inner.DoOneThing(fnMethod);
    }

    void DidSomething(int x)
    {
        cout << "Did something x = " << x << endl;
    }

    // example typedef, the actual callback has a lot of args (5 args)
    typedef std::function<void(int)> DidSomethingCallback;

private:

    class Inner
    {
    public:
        void DoOneThing(DidSomethingCallback fnDidSomething)
        {
            fnDidSomething(3);
        }
    };

    T t;
};

int main()
{
    Outer<bool> outer;
    outer.StartSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::bind` requires you to specify placeholders for unbound arguments so that the return type will know how many arguments to expect and where to pass them to. Hence you must write:

```
auto fnGlobal = std::bind(&::DidSomething, std::placeholders::_1);
```

to tell it that `fnGlobal` takes one argument and should call `::DidSomething` with that one argument. Otherwise, `fnGlobal` will take no arguments. Likewise

```
auto fnMethod = std::bind(&Outer<T>::DidSomething, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

will make `fnMethod` take one argument, call it `x`, then call `this->DidSomething(x)`. Without the placeholder, `fnMethod` will take no arguments.

The clunkiness of `std::bind` makes it desirable to avoid using it in many cases. In the first case, it suffices to write

```
// the & is optional
auto fnGlobal = ::DidSomething;
```

to make `fnGlobal` a normal function pointer. In the second case, a lambda can be used:

```
auto fnMethod = [this](int x) { DidSomething(x); };
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the lambda, seems more descriptive and clear to me. I would use the mem_fn but resulted in C2893. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) example 1 shows it needs the instance, but I think I messed this up `void DoOneThing(Outer& outer, DidSomethingCallback fnDidSomething)
        {
            fnDidSomething(outer, 300);
        }` and called it with `inner.DoOneThing(*this, fnMem);`

Comment: @ShoaevHares Sorry you're right, `mem_fn` doesn't do what I said it does. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `std::bind` the wrong way. You need to pass the corresponding number of arguments to be bound or placeholders as it may be when you create a `std::bind` object. Change:

```
    auto fnGlobal = std::bind(&::DidSomething);
    inner.DoOneThing(fnGlobal);

    auto fnMethod = std::bind(&Outer<T>::DidSomething, this);
    inner.DoOneThing(fnMethod);
```

to:

```
    auto fnGlobal = std::bind(&::DidSomething, std::placeholders::_1);
    inner.DoOneThing(fnGlobal);

    auto fnMethod = std::bind(&Outer<T>::DidSomething, this, std::placeholders::_1);
    inner.DoOneThing(fnMethod);
```

That should [work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fa62cd7d8db1e61)